# RAM issue: Laptop fails to boot with two different RAM modules?

Tags: laptop, memory, bios, boot

My laptop ([scan report from crucial website](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/2E32210031D926C3)) currently has 4GB memory: 2GB onboard, and a SO-DIMM module, 2GB 1066MHz, inserted in the ONLY slot the laptop offers.

Here starts my odyssey: I bought a 8GB 1600MHz module. In the BIOS it correctly stated 8192MB + 2048MB = 10240MB, but Windows 7 64bit failed to boot every time. "Fail to boot" clarification: "Starting Windows" appears, but the fluorescent lights never appear. Then it was that I discovered that my laptop only supports up to 8GB of memory, if what crucial reports is correct.

Question 1: is this proper hardware behavior, if more RAM than maximum supported is installed, to not boot at all the OS? Or should it normally boot with the maximum GB supported, and discard all extra RAM installed (in my case, boot with 8GB and discard the 2GB)? Because if the first is the case, then 8GB max is practically unobtainable, due to the 2GB onboard, and 4+2 = 6GB is maximum supported.

I returned the module and afted a month, just yesterday, I finally got my replacement of choice: a 4GB 1066MHz module. I got 4GB for obvious reasons, and I went with 1066MHz just to be on the safe side, as my current inserted 2GB is 1066MHz too.

As you can guess, it doesn't work too. BIOS correctly states 6144MB installed, but exactly the same boot failure as when I tested the 8GB module happens. Re-inserting my 2GB same-speed module, it boots just fine everytime.

Adding insult to injury, I tested the 4GB module on a friend's laptop and it booted just fine, so it's not faulty. Moreover, I also tested both his 4GB 1600MHz modules on my laptop, and it boots fine, so 1600MHz modules are supported by my laptop, in case I had any second thoughts if 1600Mhz speed was the reason the now-returned 8GB module didn't function.

I don't have the slightest explanation on my problems anymore. 8GB modules are out of the question as it appears that with my 2GB onboard, I jump to 10GB and it won't boot, and now what, 4GB are also out of the question, since my 4GB (that is not faulty as it works on another system) does not work, and it is 1066MHz, same speed as the 2GB module I have now inserted has.

Comment: I highly encourage you to read the text again. It does not have a PSU as it is a laptop, as stated in the title, six times in the text and with the 'laptop' tag. The model is QX310, as stated in the link. CPU is an i5 @2.67GHz. But all power-related questions are irrelevant, as as I stated in the second-to-last paragraph, a friend's 4GB 1600MHz plays just fine on my laptop, while my slightly less power-hungry 4GB 1066MHz completely fails to boot up Win7.

Comment: I would purchase the same module your friend have, without specifics to compare the two modules, I can't help.  My guess the reason Windows isn't booting is because of incompatible hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are dealing with a speed issue.

1600 . 1066 sounds like 3/2, but your machine might be coughing at the different speeds.

Have you tried to boot linux, say, from a cdrom?  This will tell you whether it's a memory problem or something to do with Windows 19;3.

It might be possible to disable the onboard ram and use the SO-DIMM alone, which means that the 8 GB ram could have been used by itself, and Windows ;3 would have no problems with internal memory.